# Unresponsive UITableView when multithreaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, performance, uitableview

I'm using UITableView to implement something like console output. I never call reloadData, only insertRowsAtIndexPaths and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths for the last line.

My problem is that the application becomes completely unresponsive when the table grow beyond 100 rows. My app spews a lot of data is less then a min. During that time the UITableView updates with less then frame per second.

```
void Log(const char* str)
{
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
  {
     // insertRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths (both withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone)
  }
}
```

If it matters my table is created in code:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:8];
}
```

and I'm using fixed rowHeight.

Comment: Instruments show me that most time is spend in animation related methods like [UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]. It feels like that queuing stuff on the mainQueue is causing my problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually more efficient to update the underlying data on a separate thread in a batch and call regularly `[tableView reloadData]` on the main thread (after a defined number of updates or time).

If you have too many updates, it is bad for performance to always switch between main an secondary thread.